# find a value from df1 in df2 and replace other values of the matching rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, compare

I have the following code with 2 dataframes (df1 & df2)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5'],
        'Number': ['456', 'A977', '132a', '6783r', '868354']}

replace = {'NewName': ['NewName1', 'NewName3', 'NewName4', 'NewName5', 'NewName2'],
        'ID': ['I753', '25552', '6783r', '868354', 'A977']}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Number'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(replace, columns = ['NewName', 'ID'])
```

Now I would like to compare every item in the 'Number' column of df1 with the 'ID' column of df2. If there is a match, I would like to replace the 'Name' of df1 with the 'NewName' of df2, otherwise it should keep the 'Name' of df1.

First I tried the following code, but unfortunately it mixed the name and the number in the different rows.

```
df1.loc[df1['Number'].isin(df2['ID']), ['Name']] = df2.loc[df2['ID'].isin(df1['Number']),['NewName']].values
```

The next code that I tried worked a bit better, but it replaced the 'Name' of df1 with the 'Number' of df1 if there was no matching.

```
df1['Name'] = df1['Number'].replace(df2.set_index('ID')['NewName'])
```

How can I stop this behavior in my last code or are there better ways in general to achieve what I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead of `replace` to substitute each value in the column `Number` in `df1` with corresponding value from the `NewName` column in `df2` then [`fill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the `NaN` values *(values which can't be substituted)* in mapped column with the original values from the `Name` column in `df1`:

```
df1['Name'] = df1['Number'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['NewName']).fillna(df1['Name'])
```

---

```
>>> df1

       Name  Number
0     Name1     456
1  NewName2    A977
2     Name3    132a
3  NewName4   6783r
4  NewName5  868354
```

Comment: Thx for your answer... I tried your soulution and it works perfectly for some data frames... but for very long ones I get the following error message... do you have any idea what it means and how to solve it?

`in get_indexer    raise InvalidIndexError( pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: In case `df2` contains the duplicate values in the `ID` column then i guess you will get that error..One idea to solve this problem is to drop the duplicate values in `ID` column in `df2`  before mapping like `df1['Number'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['NewName']).fillna(df1['Name'])`